# 'NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat' - Magick.NET in AWS Lambda Serverless API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, imagemagick

I am using Magick.NET to resize and save images to AWS S3. I have a Lambda Serverless Web API which takes requests to do this. It works fine when running locally but not when calling the live endpoint on Lambda. I get the following exception:

```
{
    "Timestamp": "2018-08-31T09:26:40.2561647+00:00",
    "Level": "Error",
    "MessageTemplate": "### Error resizing image. ###",
    "Exception": "ImageMagick.MagickMissingDelegateErrorException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/456\n   at TAP.Services.TourManagementService.<AddImage>d__24.MoveNext() in C:\\######\\TourManagementService.cs:line 180\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at TAP.API.Tours.Controllers.ImagesController.<Post>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\\######\\ImagesController.cs:line 44\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>d__23.MoveNext()",
    "Properties": {
        "ExceptionDetail": {
            "HResult": -2146233088,
            "Message": "NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/456",
            "Source": "Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU",
            "RelatedExceptions": [
                {
                    "RelatedExceptions": [],
                    "Message": "UnableToOpenConfigureFile `magic.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/714",
                    "Data": {},
                    "InnerException": null,
                    "TargetSite": null,
                    "StackTrace": null,
                    "HelpLink": null,
                    "Source": null,
                    "HResult": -2146233088
                }
            ],
            "Type": "ImageMagick.MagickMissingDelegateErrorException"
        }
    }
}
```

The image I'm trying to upload is here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6e86e0008b49ac29399c8cc2103c667820180831084315/99efdf and the code where I use Magick.NET is as follows:

```
private byte[] resizeImage(byte[] imageData, int width, int height)
{
    using (var image = new MagickImage(imageData, new MagickReadSettings { Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg }))
    {
        image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
        image.Interlace = Interlace.Jpeg; // Make image progressive

        var geometry = new MagickGeometry(width, height);
        geometry.FillArea = true;

        try
        {
            image.Resize(geometry);
            image.Crop(width, height);
            image.RePage();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.Error(ex, "Error resizing image.");
            throw new ImageResizeException("Error resizing image.", ex);
        }

        return image.ToByteArray();
    }
}
```

I've had problems with Lambda before when trying to read from local files so I thought the `UnableToOpenConfigureFile` might be a similar issue. I then used the GitHub guide (https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/Documentation/Initialization.md) to initialise MagickNET using code rather than relying on the .xml files like so:

```
var configFiles = ConfigurationFiles.Default;
configFiles.Policy.Data = @"
    <policymap>
      <policy domain=""delegate"" rights=""none"" pattern=""*"" />
      <policy domain=""coder"" rights=""none"" pattern=""*"" />
      <policy domain=""coder"" rights=""read|write"" pattern=""{GIF,JPEG,PNG,WEBP}"" />
    </policymap>";
MagickNET.Initialize(configFiles);
```

...but sadly this has not changed anything and I'm still getting the same error. As I say, this all works fine locally which makes me think it's an environment issue.

**EDIT:**

I've also just tried including the xml files in the project and publishing them directly. 
[image]

By doing this I need to tell Magick.NET where to find the files so I have tried doing with the environment variable `MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH` in Lambda, which I have set to "/MagickNet". The other method I tried was setting the path in `MagickNET.Initialize` like so:

```
MagickNET.Initialize("./MagickNet");
```

This has also failed to help me.

Comment: Other XML configure files are missing. Try packaging the XML with your lambda solution, and setting `MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH` environment variable to the location of the files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @emcconville. I've just tried that and it didn't help unfortunately. See the edit above for details.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this, I am having the same issue